# Logback can't write in console

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, spring-boot, logback

I am using Logback in my spring boot application.

The problem is logback do not print my logger messages in 'eclipse' console for my both 2 packages **dao** and **web**.

The log file is written without any problem , and print my logger messages.

I am the root so probably I should see my logger messages in my console.

- logger.info("Page X INFO");
- logger.debug(" Page X Debug ");

Here is my **logback.xml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- By default, encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Send debug messages to a file at "C:/logs/Log.log" -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>C:/logs/Log.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>C:/logs/Log.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="package.web" level="INFO" >
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="package.dao" level="DEBUG" >
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
         <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How do you get the loggers? `LoggerFactory.getLogger( Classname.class )` or explicitly `getLogger( "package.web" )`?

Comment: I am using this : private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

and then I write my message like logger.info("Page X INFO");

Comment: You may try to use `getLogger( WhatEverClassName.class )` instead. If you get dupe entries, remove the appender refs from the logger config then. As I write in my update, I'd expect the appenders to be inherited from root. Also, you can make that `private final static` which is the recommended pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<logger name="package.web" level="INFO" >
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
```

You need to add the console appender.

```
<logger name="package.web" level="INFO" >
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

UPDATE: I just reread the logback config doku. Actually, those two should inherit both appenders from root. So, what you can try is to not specify any appender-ref on those and see what happens. If no output is written to the file then, neither - then there is something pretty strange. I'd expect that behavior if the additivity flag was set to false. But the default is appender accumulation.

Comment: It works, as you said they should inherit from root.
*Thank you*

Comment: My last code is :
<logger name="package.web" level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
 </logger>
 <logger name="package.dao" level="DEBUG">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
 </logger>
 <root level="DEBUG">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
 </root>